# How to assign different Url to my TreeView Items

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I am new to Qt. I had created a Qtree View using QStandard item model.
Now I want to set Url to my items. How can I assign url for tree view items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setData API of QStandardItem, with user defined role for storing URL.

```
void QStandardItem::setData ( const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::UserRole + 1 )
```